# How to integrate Keycloak with Spring (boot-less)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, keycloak

I've been trying to get my Spring web application to work with Keycloak without any luck for days now. I followed the instructions mentioned in their documentation [here](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html).

I have setup a Keycloak server running in Wildfly 9. For my web application, I'm using JBoss AS 7 with Spring Framework 4.1.7. I have configured the adapter for my JBoss AS 7 following the steps [here](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#jboss-adapter). Then for my Spring web application I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/html/ch08.html#spring-security-adapter). However, when I try to run my application, it doesn't redirect to my Keycloak server. It just displays the page without requiring any authentication.

Please see my code below.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak</artifactId>
  <name>demo-keycloak-mvc</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.15</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Keycloak -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.Final</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

  <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
  <annotation-driven />

  <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
  <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.demo.keycloak" />



</beans:beans>
```

security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity" />

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="adapterDeploymentContextBean" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextBean" />
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProvider" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider" />
    <bean id="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" />
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="keycloakLogoutHandler" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakLogoutHandler">
            <constructor-arg ref="adapterDeploymentContextBean" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="logoutSuccessUrl" value="/" />
        <constructor-arg name="handlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="keycloakLogoutHandler" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="logoutRequestMatcher">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
                <constructor-arg name="pattern" value="/sso/logout**" />
                <constructor-arg name="httpMethod" value="GET" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="logoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
    </security:http>

</beans>
```

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "demorealm",
  "realm-public-key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8g2TQ1HLuPryt0uygtRLQP29OQSTYcgLbrpCOhxvumghB+meTeI6eXdY3RT29oPI5C39oETo74eaoyG2eIKAfy/hcuQotEFwPus03iKAlXQFf5h7Sf8UUdCcCWNXakSpyCpkFqFlNcDJBdvUdgtogY4vznauCGexnP4lAuIlgdL7aYse1xUtWhNMVFjRr/fCnkabsJo+E6NqnjYmbnsuBrgeWB6chRP8CfnAK2Q4MeARIiSUZbXL8MX9etB4d15nc2llUl/PzDIJ7sD3U70+1LIU8bzanYErCxz7f07hx96kHHPLtH58r+d9YrjJtjMFsd9AO4r1YesdlnAshxPccwIDAQAB",
  "auth-server-url": "https://mykeycloakurl.com/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "demo",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "e140dbb8-22ba-4ba7-9b54-73e688e937da"
  }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package org.demo.keycloak;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

  /**
   * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
   */
  @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

    return "home";
  }

}
```

[image: Project Structure]

Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE 08/18/2015**

I got this from the application server(JBoss AS 7) log file after setting level to DEBUG in JBoss standalone and adding loggers in log4j.xml in my application. It's a bit lenghty and was not able to paste it here so I pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/JSbDXbjF) instead. Hopefully it helps.

**UPDATE 08/26/2015**

I tried the other approach which is to setup the web.xml file with security constraints and removed spring security adapter reference in the pom.xml file and used keycloak core and keycloak adapter core instead. It now redirects to my Keycloak server. However, when I login using the username and password, I get redirected back to the web url but it returns an error with Http Status 403 Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak</artifactId>
    <name>demo-keycloak-mvc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.7.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Home</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>demorealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

Keycloak server configurations:

Realm: demorealm

Client Settings:

- Client: demo
- Client Protocol: openid-connect
- Access Type: confidential
- Valid Redirect Urls: http://localhost:8080/*
- Base Url: http://localhost:8080

Client Scope:

- Full scope allowed: TRUE

Still no luck. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please enable debug logging on org.springframework.security.web package and post the output of your application during startup?

Comment: Hi @Scott. Updated my post above and added the information you requested.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the security context being initialized in the logs you posted. Will try to test tonight.

Comment: Hi @Scott. Did you get a chance to look at this?

Comment: The first here link is outdated and can be referred here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter

Answer (score 2):

When using the Keycloak Spring Security Adapter, you shouldn't use any other Keycloak adapters in the same project.

Your configuration files look ok, but the behavior you describe makes it sound like Spring isn't picking up your security rules.

Comment: Hi. I don't think I'm using any other Keycloak adapters. I only have the keycloak-spring-security-adapter in my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct role to the user I had created plus the below changes in keycloak.json fixed the 403 issues for me.

```
  "use-resource-role-mappings": false,
```